# PHP MongoDB Driver Query using an Array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to build a query in my PHP application against a MongoDB and want to check if there are any records that match an array of email addresses.  The record has a nested object in it as well, so I am not 100% sure the right syntax and if it's even possible to do it this way. Appreciate any help and advice.

Nest Object:

> Owner => Email

Code:

```
$emails = array ('abc@def.com', 'asd@qwe.com', 'obd@rew.com');

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([ "Owner" => [ 'Email' => $emails ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query("Owner.Email" => array ( '$in' => $emails));
```